# How to debug Lua remotely?

Tags: debugging, http, lua

I'm searching for the best way to debug Lua remotely, ( like from a web browser ).

I saw [RemDebug](http://www.keplerproject.org/remdebug/), but the last project update was done on 2006. It works with Lua 5.0 and 5.1, but Lua 5.2 is quite close, and I don't see RemDebug to get an update anytime soon.

I could mount a small embedded web-server on my debug host, and use something like RemDebug to communicate with it, and perform remote debugging via HTTP.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need web-browser based client. Is a client which is based on a full blown debugger good for you?

Comment: Hey there, I work in Game Development, I need something generic that I can compile and run on several architectures. Making a Web-Browser based client would be ideal for me.

Answer (score 12):

I have developed a new debugger based on RemDebug ([MobDebug](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug)) with new commands, new features, bugfixes, and integration with IDEs.

MobDebug is based on TCP interaction between the client (debugee) and the server (controller). This is also the case for RemDebug and most other remote debuggers. You might be able to run on top of something else (like WebSockets or HTTP), but you still need to be able to run coroutines and debug hook to control the application being debugged.

The architecture of the debugging process is quite simple:

- You have an application you want to debug
- You also have your debugger with a controller
- The application loads the client components of the debugger, which opens a connection to the controller
- The controller accepts commands from a command line or an IDE (MobDebug provides both; it integrates with [ZeroBraneStudio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) and also provides a scriptable way to run it)
- When the application is loaded, the debugger installs a debug hook, which is run on every line/call/return. From this debug hook a resume call is made to the debugger, which can then execute commands from the controller (like install a breakpoint, evaluate an expression and so on). When the next executable command is send (like run or step), the debugger yields back to the hook, which then returns back to the app allowing it to proceed.

It may be possible to mimic the existing socket interface (as it's only using connect/send/receive and select/timeout to abort the application) and reuse most of the library. I'm still not sure why you'd want to run this in a browser though as you can run the application on anything that supports TCP already (I have a working prototype debugging an application running on a mobile device from my desktop).

Comment: I really like what I see here... I'll give it a try!

Comment: Your debugger looks great! Is there a tutorial for beginners (I have already seen the examples folder)? Some things are not self-explanatory and the `help` is not that thorough.

Comment: @Atcold, you may want to check [this overview](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging) and other [debugging-related links](http://studio.zerobrane.com/documentation.html#debugging). They are from the perspective of a user of the IDE, but since all that functionality is based on what MobDebug provides, it may give you additional insight into how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Hillin's Remote Lua Debugger 1.2.0.218](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/Hillin-s-Remote-Lua-Debugger.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure if you need to debug lua remotely or ask about doing so over HTTP; I'm answering about the former and am not aware of a way to do so over HTTP.

Both [LuaEdit](http://luaedit.luaforge.net/) and [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda) allow you to connect remotely to a running lua script (both on a different process on the same machine and on a remote machine).

Decoda can do magic and do so for a lua VM without requiring any change to the VM; with LuaEdit you need to create the VM in a specific way, using a provided DLL or library.

Comment: This are not web-based ... I'm thinking about developing the web based client myself, but I would need some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is right. Hope it helps though:

Source: http://www.keplerproject.org/remdebug/example.html

This is an example of a debugging session of the following script (test.lua):

```
 1    require"remdebug.engine"
 2
 3    remdebug.engine.start()
 4    
 5    local tab = {
 6      foo = 1,
 7      bar = 2
 8    }
 9
10    print("Start")
11
12    function bar()
13      print("In bar 1")
14      print("In bar 2")
15    end
16
17    for i = 1, 10 do
18      print("Loop")
19      bar()
20      tab.foo = tab.foo * 2
21    end
22
23    print("End")
```

First run the RemDebug controller:

% lua50 controller.lua
Lua Remote Debugger
Run the program you wish to debug
At this moment you can run your target program (in another window):

% lua50 test.lua
Now go back to the window where you ran controller.lua (this assumes you are running test.lua inside C:\development\kepler on a Windows system):

Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua
Type 'help' for commands

> basedir C:/development/kepler/
>   New base directory is C:/development/kepler/
>   basedir
>   C:/development/kepler/
>   step
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 6
>   over
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 7
>   over
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 10
>   over
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 15
>   setb test.lua 19
>   run
>   You can change to the application window anytime to see its output. Back to the debugger session:

Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 19

> run
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 19
>   eval tab.foo
>   2
>   eval tab.bar
>   2
>   exec old_tab = tab
>   nil
>   exec tab = 2
>   nil
>   eval tab
>   2
>   exec tab = old_tab
>   nil
>   eval tab.foo
>   2
>   run
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 19
>   eval tab.foo
>   4
>   delb test.lua 19
>   setw tab.foo == 32
>   Inserted watch exp no. 1
>   run
>   Paused at file C:/development/kepler/test.lua line 17
>     (watch expression 1: [tab.foo = 32])
>   eval tab.foo
>   32
>   delw 1
>   run
>   Program finished

Comment: In the original question I specified that I saw RemDebug, but Lua 5.2 is quite close, and I don't see RemDebug to get an update anytime soon. I don't really see this as a suitable answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for web-browser debugging (the idea seems weird to me, maybe you can detail why you would need a web-browser debugger ?)

For a standalone debugger however, I've written a remote debugger with GUI : http://cushy-code.com/grld

It communicates with the debugged program with the socket API, so any network connection will do, no need for HTTP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this sounds very interesting, but I need an open source solution in order to understand how to do it. ( The question is "how to debug lua remotely" ) Thanks.