# How to read variables values from Lua running process ( obtain process variable value )?

Tags: c++, variables, interface, process, lua

I tried some attempts to run a Lua code, and retrieve its values while its running trough `C/C++` like so, but My application crashes by segmentation fault.

eg. accessing memory that is not rightfully mine:

So far I got this. Simple process, with the Lua interpreter:

```
a = {5}

local Cnt1 = 0
local Cnt2 = 0
while true do
  Cnt2 = Cnt2 + 1
  if(Cnt2 == 100000000) then
    Cnt2 = 0
    print("Irer: "..Cnt1.." Address: "..tostring(a).." Value: "..a[1])
    Cnt1 = Cnt1 + 1
  end
end
```

The infinite loop is actually for keeping the process wake and table address constant.

As you see I print the address of "a", which I copy paste it to C ( Code Blocks ) from the console itself. After that I wrote another program, where I hard coded the pointer as a memory map like so:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)0x78C070;
printf("Value: %u",*p);
return 0;
```

Possible ways are
1) Way I can try is a file, but it's really slow ( HDD )

2) File on the ram-disk - fast, but not everyone have a ram-disk.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointers. Also, if you don't mind some extra C code, you can use `mmap` to share memory.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Please give us the ten thousand foot view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a C wrapper program and use the Lua C API to retrieve values.  Here's an example that should to retrieve your "a".  There's no error handling, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

```
lua_State *L = sys_lua_L();
luaL_loadfile(L, "your_lua_script.lua");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
lua_getglobal(L, "a"); // retrieve lua variable a
lua_rawgeti(L, -1, 1); // assumes "a" is a table
int val = lua_tointegerL, -1);
printf("%d\n", val);
```

Comment: But does this just open the file and executes it ...I was talking about a running process. You see here my file is already running, rather than open and execute it from C. If u run this the file will be opened again and the address of the table will be different ( same "a", same value, but on a different address in the memory )

Comment: That is true!  I misunderstood your question.  If you're only trying to determine the running state of the program, you could use a remote debugger, like: http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging.html or one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438751/how-to-debug-lua-remotely .  Alternatively, you could run it inside a C program with a signal handler that dumped the state of the Lua globals when a certain signal was received.